# I have performed partial match using cosine similarity but unable to get counts properly

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes - s2 (Log file with Query and Response columns) and s1 (reference file containing Category, Question, Response) - I have done cosine similarity on Response column of both s1 and s2 and have got 'answer' dataframe.
Next, I have merged with s2 in order to get corresponding question and category - t1 is the resulting table.
Now, from t1, I want to find count of s1.Response in combination with Question using a filter or any way, please tell me how to do it.

```
s2 <- data.frame(Category =c("Stationary","TransferRelocationClaim","IMS"),
Question =c( "Where do I get stationary items from?","Process for claiming Transfer relocation allowances.","What is IMS?"),Response = c("Hey <firstname>, you will find it near helpdesk ","Hey <firstname>, moving to new places can be fun! To claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon).","ims or interview management system is a tool that helps interviewers schedule all the interviews"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

s1 <- data.frame(
Question = c("Where to get books?", "Procedure to order stationary?","I would like to know about my relocation and relocation expenses","tell me about relocation expense claiming","how to claim relocation expense","IMS?"),
Response = c("Hey Anil, you will find it at the helpdesk.", "Hey, Shekhar, you will find it at the helpdesk.", "hey sonali moving to new places can be fun! to claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon)","hey piyush moving to new places can be fun! to claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,assignments ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon). 3. attach the bills to the printout and secure approval sign-off / mail (from the pa support for new joinee relocation claims and the portal approver for existing employees). 4. drop the bills in the portal drop box (the duty manager amp, finance team can confirm the coordinates.", "hey vibha moving to new places can be fun! to claim relocation expense please follow the steps given below- 1. request you to add the code in https://portal.mycompany.com ,assignments ,enter relocation code ,add. 2. select expenses ,add expense ,other expense ,fill the form ,save ,print (select the print icon). 3. attach the bills to the printout and secure approval sign-off / mail from the pa support for new joinee relocation claims and the portal approver for existing employees). 4. drop the bills in the portal drop box (the duty manager amp, finance team can confirm the coordinates", "ims or interview management system is a tool that helps interviewers schedule all the interviews"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

s1$Response=gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',s1$Response)
s2$Response=gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',s2$Response)
s1$Response <- tolower(s1$Response)
s2$Response <- tolower(s2$Response)
s1$Response<-as.character(s1$Response)
s2$Response<-as.character(s2$Response)
# data =s1, lookup=s2
d.matrix <- stringdistmatrix(a = s2$Response, b = s1$Response, useNames="strings",method="cosine", nthread = getOption("sd_num_thread"))

#list of minimun cosines
cosines<-apply(d.matrix, 2, min)

#return list of the row number of the minimum value
minlist<-apply(d.matrix, 2, which.min) 

#return list of best matching values
matchwith<-s2$Response[minlist]

#below table contains best match and cosines
answer<-data.frame(s1$Response, matchwith, cosines)
t1=merge(x=answer,y=s2, by.x="matchwith", by.y="Response", all.x=TRUE)
View(t1)`
```

[image: t1 table looks like as shown below]

How to find count of s1.Response in combination with Question using a filter or any easy way. Currently this dataframe is very large, here I have provided few records. I can't manually pass Question list as its too many, kindly let me know, how to get count of s1.Response for each Question in s2 dataframe.

Expected output in dataframe:
For Question: Process for claiming relocation claims - count should come 3,
For Question: IMS? - count should come as 1,
For Question: Where do I get stationary? - count should come 2.

Comment: In the dataframe, the column is `Question` but later you are using `Response`. Please correct it

Comment: may I know which line you are referring to?

Comment: First 2 lines s1 and s2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` function to group and summarise as below:

```
library(dplyr)
t1 %>%
  group_by(Question) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Question                                                 n
  <chr>                                                <int>
1 Process for claiming Transfer relocation allowances.     3
2 What is IMS?                                             1
3 Where do I get stationary items from?                    2
```

Comment: No, still its coming incorrect. In my output: I want s1.Response count from 't1' dataframe, corresponding question and category from s2.                                                For ex: for Question 'Process for claiming transfer' , I should get s1.Response count as 3 along with category name as 'TransferRelocationClaim"

Comment: Can you update the question with the expected output based on the data that you have shared?

Comment: yup, I have updated it, there was some confusion in naming s1 and s2, now its modified in code above.

Comment: @Sand Then you need to group by Question field. See updated answer

Comment: For some, it gives count correctly, and for some its coming incorrect. Will share result in sometime

Comment: Just to be sure of count, is there a way to combine both Question and partial sentence of s1.Response from t1 to get count

Comment: I tried the above code on a bigger dataset, however its not resulting in correct count as responses are having partial match with a difference in 2 or 3 words. Can anyone suggest to filter by partial sentence of s1.Response and Question so that I get correct count.from t1